# Add manufacturer name in featured module

Tags: php, twig, opencart

I am trying to add **manufacturer** name in Featured module in OpenCart v3. However, when I write the following in Featured module it doesn't show up, I think I am missing something.

```
<a href="{{ manufacturers }}">{{ manufacturer }}</a>
```

Comment: Could you please post a reproducible example of what you´re trying to do, with code?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit the controller file for the featured module. Go to store/catalog/controller/extension/module/featured.php, find the line below (should be line 37):

```
if ((float)$product_info['special']) {
    $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);
} else {
    $special = false;
}
```

We need to check if there is a Manufacturer linked to the product before we assign it to a new variable. Add the following below the last closing brace:

```
if(isset($product_info['manufacturer'])) {
    $manufacturer = $product_info['manufacturer'];  
} else {
    $manufacturer = "";
}

if(isset($product_info['manufacturer_id'])) {
    $manufacturer_url = $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $product_info['manufacturer_id']);
} else {
    $manufacturer_url = "";
}
```

Then add it to the array that is passed to the view (twig file). Find the line below (should be line 73):

```
'rating'      => $rating,
```

Add the newly created variables to array indexes that you can easily reference in the twig file:

```
'manufacturer' => $manufacturer,
'manufacturer_url' => $manufacturer_url,
```

Now open the twig file (catalog/view/extension/module/featured.twig), go to the place that you want to display the manufacturer and add the lines below - the first line checks if the `manufacturer` variable is not null (when the manufacturer is not set for the product):

```
{% if product.manufacturer %}
  <p><a href="{{ product.manufacturer_url }}">{{ product.manufacturer }}</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps you.

NB - you may find that the change doesn't reflect on the front end of the store, you may need to clear your template cache, if you're doing more development, you should disable cache until you're ready to go into a production environment:

Click this button on the Dashboard:

[image: Button to access developer settings]

Now click "Off" for the options you need to disable:

[image: Developer Settings]